# Having issue with rendering table rows with list of dictionaries using django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm having issue with rendering the table rows by passing list of dictionaries using django-tables2.

```
views.py
========

list_of_dict = [{"File Path": 'path1', "Age": 500, "No of files": 90},
                {"File Path": 'path2', "Age": 400, "No of files": 25}]
nt = Small_table(list_of_dict)

RequestConfig(request).configure(nt)
return render(request, "collectionsec.html", {"small": nt})

tables.py
=========

import django_tables2 as tables

class Small_table (tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column()
    age = tables.Column()
    nof = tables.Column()

    class meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-responsive', 'width': '100%'}

collectionsec.html
==================

{% load django_tables2 %}
{% render_table small %}
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
Name Age Nof
—   —   —
—   —   —
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the issue was!
The inner class should be named 'Meta' rather than what I had 'meta'